# Why do the TAILQ_INSERT_* macros require an entry to be bound to a variable?

Tags: c, linux, queue, bsd

When using the tail queue implementation from `sys/queue.h`, why does the following code work:

```
item_t *item = mkitem(...);
TAILQ_INSERT_HEAD(&list, item, entry);
```

while the following, which should be equivalent, does not:

```
TAILQ_INSERT_HEAD(&list, mkitem(...), entry);
```

## Minimal working example

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/queue.h>

typedef struct item item_t;
typedef TAILQ_HEAD(list_head, item) list_head_t;

struct item {
    int value;
    TAILQ_ENTRY(item) entry;
};

static list_head_t items = TAILQ_HEAD_INITIALIZER(items);

static item_t* mkitem(int i) {
    item_t *item = calloc(1, sizeof(item_t));
    item->value = i;
    return item;
}

static void print_tailq() {
    item_t *it;
    TAILQ_FOREACH(it, &items, entry) {
        printf("%d,", it->value);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    item_t *i1, *i2, *i3;

    i1 = mkitem(1);
    i2 = mkitem(2);
    i3 = mkitem(3);

    TAILQ_INSERT_HEAD(&items, i1, entry);
    print_tailq();
    TAILQ_INSERT_HEAD(&items, i2, entry);
    print_tailq();
    TAILQ_INSERT_TAIL(&items, i3, entry);
    print_tailq();

    /* However, this does not work: */
    TAILQ_INSERT_HEAD(&items, mkitem(4), entry);
    print_tailq();
    TAILQ_INSERT_HEAD(&items, mkitem(5), entry);
    print_tailq();
    TAILQ_INSERT_TAIL(&items, mkitem(6), entry);
    print_tailq();

    return 0;
}
```

As expected, the first three invocations of `print_tailq()` print out, respectively:

```
1,
2,1,
2,1,3,
```

However, the last three invocations show that the list is truncated by `TAILQ_INSERT_HEAD`, and `TAILQ_INSERT_TAIL` is essentially a no-op.

```
4,
5,
5,
```

Comment: Yes, it does. I would expect the output of the fourth,  fifth and sixth call to `print_tailq` to be `4,2,1,3,`, `5,4,2,1,3,` and `5,4,2,1,3,6,`, respectively. The actual output is given in the question.

Comment: Ok I will try too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://unix.superglobalmegacorp.com/xnu/newsrc/bsd/sys/queue.h.html) the implementation of `TAILQ_INSERT_HEAD` macro `TAILQ_INSERT_HEAD(head, elm, field)`

```
#define TAILQ_INSERT_HEAD(head, elm, field) do {                \
    if (((elm)->field.tqe_next = (head)->tqh_first) != NULL)    \
        (head)->tqh_first->field.tqe_prev =                     \
            &(elm)->field.tqe_next;                             \
    else                                                        \
        (head)->tqh_last = &(elm)->field.tqe_next;              \
    (head)->tqh_first = (elm);                                  \
    (elm)->field.tqe_prev = &(head)->tqh_first;                 \
} while (0)
```

It is macro which is being expanded - so it is basically replacing the `elm` with multiple calls to `mkitem()`. Passing directly the results of `mkitem()` invokes erroneous behavior in your code. Using `mkitem` directly overwrites the previous list (there is a memory leak) and the new list with single element is created - which is printed.  You have to use a variable here like you did earlier - otherwise it won't work. Actually you thought that this is a function which it is not. (You will see that `man` page examples also reflect this idea of using a variable)